# Where is Point Cloud?

Tags: modeling, interface, osx

Just downloaded version 2.92 for Mac. I am unable to find the Point Cloud option in the Add menu. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ben you mention you've seen videos where p.c. exists in the add menu.  Perhaps you could stop the video at that point, take a screen print, and include it in your question?  They say a picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 3):

Go to *Edit-> Preferences -> Interface* and check Developer Extras

This will create new tab in left column called **Experimental**.

In that tab you need to check **New Point Cloud Type**.

Comment: I can confirm this, however, this seems to be only in 2.93 up and 2.92 daily releases. 2.92 Stable does not have that menu entry.

Comment: confirm for 3.0.0 alpha

Comment: I have Developer Extras enabled and when I look at the Experimental tab, all I have is a Debugging section.  No "New Point Cloud Type".  2.93 (.3 and .5)

Answer (score 2):

Pointcloud is not a generic object type in the add section.
It exist in the geometry node editor section as "Point Distribute".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've seen several videos where people add Point Cloud from the Add menu. In the videos, it shows up right between "Text" and "Volume". Except not when I try it.